# How To Declare Traversable Type?

Tags: php, types, phpdoc, psalm-php

There are multiple typehints in PHP, more now in PHP 8, and even more with Psalm. But what about *declaring* the type, rather than hinting the expected type?

I have a `interface Collection extends Traversable`, and I need to declare that it is a traversable of type `Abc`. How can I do that, so that PHPDoc or Psalm know that when I iterate over instances of my `Collection`, each element will be of type `Abc`?

In other words, I need to, on *interface* level, guarantee that the assertion will always pass:

```php
function doWithItems(Collection $items): void
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        assert($item instanceof Abc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a working interface example in my code (and these can be tricky to get right), but since Psalm implements [`interface Traversable<TKey, TValue>` template](https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/templated_annotations/#builtin-templated-classes-and-interfaces) on Traversable it would be something like:

```php
/**
 * @extends Traversable<array-key,Abc>
 */
interface Collection extends Traversable
```

A definitely working class-level example from my code using [Doctrine Collections](https://github.com/doctrine/collections) (which has very thorough Psalm support, you can look through source for how they do it):

```php
/**
 * @extends ArrayCollection<array-key, ShowInterface>
 */
final class Shows extends ArrayCollection
```